# Replacing string within page with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replace a string within a tag in my html page at specific position. I have to do it often and match exactly specific string. For example, if I have:

```
<style id="myStyle">
    h1 {
      background-color: red;  
    }

    h2 {
      background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

I have to replace h2 background-color but not h1. Do I have to rewrite every time text within style tag? Or there is some better solution that splitting, recombining the entire string and then replacing tag's content(could be very big).

JavaScript replace function is not good, it doesn't replace at specific position.

Comment: This is not something CSS is designed to do well.  You may want to consider approaching this by adding and removing classes instead of trying to edit the styles directly.

Comment: It is about JavaScript replacing strings. I need a solution to this problem, everything else is not good for me.

Comment: @coldSense maybe when you add new content with JS the new stuff isn't styled, but as Mike says, adding classes is the way to go

Comment: Thanks ajax33321 but you're not helpful. In the question I explained my specific need. I have to change style tag's content not dynamically add classes or styles to some element.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can change the style of all the h1 elements currently in the DOM like so:

```
$('h1').css({
    'background-color': 'red'
});
```

You cannot actually alter what is within the style tags. But you can alter the styles of elements on the page using javascript/jQuery. The above code illustrates this

Comment: Only for `h1`s already on the page. Answer is ok, but needs this side note.

Comment: Does it replace the code within style tag? Or just for all h2 tags in the page?

Comment: @coldSense It doesn't replace any code in the style tag. This cannot be done! What it does its apply different styles to the h1 elements on the page. These styles will override the other styles as they will be applied inline!

Comment: @Ben Carey you exaggerate a little when you're saying it cannot be done.  I'm just not very sure how to do it efficiently. It is like replacing the content of some tag. JavaScript's replace() is something similar but it works on first matched string. I need string replacement at specific position.

Comment: @coldSense Why do you need to remove the tag? You shouldn't be using inline styles anyway. You should define all styles in a stylesheet... You can control elements in the DOM using javascript, but the style tags appear in the head, this is not the DOM so they cannot be manipulated. But as I have said, this does not matter as changing the style with jQuery will override anything set in the style tag!

Comment: @Ben Carey I need to write styles to style tag because I want to apply them dynamically by class, by tag or by any other selector. After that, I want to export the content of style tag and send it to another app that will use it. If I use jQuery's css method it would write style inline an then I couldn't understand which property is for a specific class, and which is for the element only(like element id).

Comment: In other words, styles should be persisted between sessions and should be personalizable.

Comment: @coldSense Then you need to come up with a completely different algorithm! You cannot export the contents of the style tag. You would be better off storing the changed styles in a database...

Comment: @Ben Carey, I would do this like: myAjaxExportFunction($("myStyle").text()); Very simple. The problem is modifying efficiently the content of the tag.

Comment: Nothing is impossible ;)

Comment: @coldSense Proof that the code posted in that fiddle is invalid: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp. A style tag cannot have an id attribute. It is possible because jQuery is not respecting the w3 document standards, it is simply searching the document for any tag with an id of `myStyle`. You can use jQuery to get the contents using `$('style')`, but again, I would advise against this and hugely urge you to find another way. Just my advice :-)

Comment: @Ben Carey actually I don't care about that. Not W3C compliant? Ok, then maybe I'll use $("style").text();,maybe... anyway it works. I'm not interested in some debate about how  theoretically perfect is my code but if it works or not. I'm not a philosopher, I'm an engineer. I have to make trade-offs. In the end, I didn't even asked help on that.

Comment: P.S. Anyway, if you're advocating something, do it well, with some solid argumentations. I won't use your approach because you think it is better to do that way. I could use it if you prove(scientifically) that it is better than mine. And, of course, if I'm interested in solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with jQuery easily

```
$('h1').css("cssText", 
"background-color: green; other-css-properties;" );
```

If you really want to be specific you could give an id or a class to whatever you want to change and do something like

```
$("#given-id").css(...) for ids and $(".given-class").css(...) for classes
```

Comment: Please read carefully the question. I appreciate that you're trying to help but it's not what I asked for. It changes style attribute of h1 not content of style tag.

Answer (score -1):

Give the h2 an id of "h2" and then have whatever event you want that triggers the change execute the following line.

```
document.getElementsById("h2")[0].setAttribute("style","color: red; background-color: gray;");
```

Comment: No. Please *do not* give your h2 an id of "h2". Just don't. If you want to do it this way, you can simply use `document.getElementsByTagName("h2")`.